# Remove duplicate pattern (dutch number and postal code) REGEX

Tags: python, python-re

I would like to remove duplicates with regex in python but I'm struggling a bit.

```
text= 'H. Gerhardstraat 77 1502 CC 77 1502 CC Zaandam'
text = re.sub(r'\b(\d{,4})\s(\d{4})\s([A-Za-z]){2}\b', r'\1', text) 

print(text)
```

I would like to get 'H. Gerhardstraat 77 1502 CC Zaandam'

I now get this :
'H. Gerhardstraat 77 77 Zaandam'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the forth argument `count` of `re.sub(pattern, repl, string, count=0, flags=0)` as follows:

```
text= 'H. Gerhardstraat 77 1502 CC 77 1502 CC Zaandam'
pattern = r'(\d{0,4}\s\d{4}\s[A-Za-z]{2}\s+)'
count  = len(re.findall(pattern, text))

if count > 1:
    text = re.sub(pattern, '', text, count -1)
```

Comment: This also removes the pattern when its not duplicate.

Comment: @user773674 It was just an example code which removes only 1 duplicate from the whatever number of duplicates are present in the text (if just one, then it will be removed as expected). You could just extend this to whatever used case you have. Anyhow please find updated snippet.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
import re

c = re.compile(r'([\w\.]+)(?!.*\1)')
text = 'H. Gerhardstraat 77 1502 CC 77 1502 CC Zaandam'

print(' '.join(c.findall(text)))
```

output :

```
H. Gerhardstraat 77 1502 CC Zaandam
```

[Link to Demo](https://regex101.com/r/8wtc6f/1)

**Explanation** : We match every words including period with `[\w\.]+` only if there isn't any same word later using *negative lookahead assertion*. `\1` here points to `([\w\.]+)` group.

This way we only get the last occurrence of the words in the list.